# Trouble with subrange declaration

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Im trying to make it so once different text is entered the shape will change color but it says theres a problem with ('A .. 'Z') being 'Expected ) but received a string literal ''A'' '. and im not sure how to fix it. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
type
  TCapitalLetter = ('A' .. 'Z' ); //subrange of type char
  TDigit = ('0' .. '9' ); //subrage of type char
```

Comment: "it says theres a problem" is not a description of the problem that is useful to us. What **exact** error message are you getting from the compiler? (And yes, I know what the problem is and how to fix it, but you need to [edit] your question and improve it first.)

Comment: From this 'problem' you can probably tell im inexperienced. I'm probably missing something very simple so i didnt think i needed to expand more than this.

Comment: I'm trying to explain how to write better questions here so you can get help faster. You have the compiler error message right in front of you; there is absolutely **no excuse** for not including it in your question. If you want us to give you **our time** to help solve **your problem**, you can at least give us the information you already have available we can use to do so.

Comment: Well, i've changed the code to what you helped with on my previous question 'Delphi 2010 password strength meter' (Thank you by the way) but this time there is an error with ('A' .. 'Z') saying: Expected ) but received a string literal ''A''. I'll attempt editing this question... If it helps.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing when you paste your code here, but every time there are what seem to be 50+ trailing space characters at the end of each line, which is screwing up the formatting. I've fixed it (again). You do see that you can preview the question as you enter it (right below the area you're typing), so you can see what it will look like when you post it, right?

Comment: @user The first thing to do when struggling with syntax is to read the documentation. Had you done so you'd see that you were using syntax for an enumerated type and not a subrange. My advice to you is to learn your way around the language guide section of the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is close, but it's not quite right:

```
type
  TCapitalLetter = 'A'..'Z';
  TDigit = '0'..9';
```

From your other question, though, I don't think that's what you really need to do. You're looking for membership (some character being contained in that type), in which case you need to do it using sets. It's a console application you can just compile and test:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TCapitalLetters = TSysCharSet; 
  TDigits = TSysCharSet;

const
  CapitalLetters: TCapitalLetters = ['A'..'Z'];
  Digits: TDigits = ['0'..'9'];

var
  Temp, Output: string;
  Ch: Char;

begin
  Output := '';
  Temp := 'Seems A Nice Test Answer';
  for Ch in Temp do
    if CharInSet(Ch, CapitalLetters) then
      Output := Output + Ch;

  WriteLn(Output);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

For earlier (non-Unicode) versions of Delphi, you need to use `set of Char` instead of `TSysCharSet`, and use a slightly different syntax for the set membership:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TCapitalLetters = set of Char;
  TDigits = set of Char;

const
  CapitalLetters: TCapitalLetters = ['A'..'Z'];
  Digits: TDigits = ['0'..'9'];

var
  Temp, Output: string;
  Ch: Char;

begin
  Output := '';
  Temp := 'Seems A Nice Test Answer';
  for Ch in Temp do
    if Ch in CapitalLetters then
      Output := Output + Ch;

  WriteLn(Output);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Output of test app:

[image: Screen capture of test app output]

Comment: Literally just needed to remove the brackets... Knew it would be something small. Whereas your second suggestion, it is a nice idea but not a password strength meter like what I am trying to make. Thank you though. With the code I have now there are still problems in which the shape wont change color at all now until any text is completely backspaced. I'll look into this more tomorrow. Thanks again!

Comment: Your "password strength meter" is going to need to iterate through the text the user enters to see how many UPPER, lower, and digits are entered, right? The code I used in my second sample will allow you to do just that, if you add the test for lowercase and digits, and implement counters instead of just collecting the letters.

Comment: set of char will not compile in Unicode Delphi, sadly. In any case it's cleaner to use character property testers like TCharacter.IsUpper and so on.

Comment: @David: Actually, it does compile, although it generates a hint about using `CharInSet` (tested in a new console app in XE5). <strike>I'll update</strike> I've updated to reflect both, though. The question (in the other post I referenced) clearly asked about 'A'..'Z' and '0'..'9'; I agree the Unicode-appropriate way would be to use `TCharacter` functionality, though. (Also look at the revision history of the original question here.)

Comment: I'm not that fussed about revision history. Not sure how set of char compiles. Perhaps compiler cheats! Sure it won't let me do set of Word! Anyway, irrespective of whether the user acknowledges characters beyond ASCII, it's always a good plan to gently remind them that latin is not the only fruit.

Comment: @David: The suggestion about revision history was related to what the original question actually was here (see revision #3). :-) As far as how it compiles with `set of Char`, my XE5 is the default configuration except for the default target for Android being a Nexus 7 tablet, and I'm not sure how 'set of Word' relates to 'set of Char'.

Comment: Ok, original question title was weird I agree. Delphi sets are only allowed over a base type of size 256 or lower. Char and Word are the same ordinality. I'm sure set of Word does not compiler because it infringes the 256 rule. So how does Char get away with it I wonder. Perhaps compiler actually gives you set of AnsiChar!

Comment: @David: OK, got the ref to `Word`. :-) The poster's other question (related to "password strength meter") has some background relevant to my answer here as well, as I mentioned in my second text paragraph. I'm glad you pointed out the diffs, though; I think the two versions of the code are relevant regardless of the character set being used.

Comment: The compiler warning describes exactly what happens: **W1050 WideChar reduced to byte char in set expressions.** The advice in the warning to use `CharInSet` seems to rather miss the point. Nothing is going to let you recover the fact that `set of char` is transformed into `set of AnsiChar`!